# Proving $\sum_{i=0}^K(-1)^i\binom{2n+1-i}{i}\binom{2n-2i}{K-i}=\frac{1}{2}(1+(-1)^K)$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

I encountered the following binomial equality:

$$\sum_{i=0}^K(-1)^i\binom{2n+1-i}{i}\binom{2n-2i}{K-i}=\frac{1}{2}(1+(-1)^K)$$

which I know it's true, but I don't know how to prove it directly. I entered the left-hand-side to Mathematica, and it directly gave me the right-hand-side. So I wonder if anyone knows an elementary proof.

Comment: What is $n$ in your formula? Is there any relation between $n$ and $K$?

Comment: @DavidP: It comes from some counting problem that I encountered.

Comment: @AnishRay: $n\geq K$ is arbitrary

Comment: @AmandaTaylor I suggest you [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4597569/edit) your question to describe the counting problem this came from in detail. For combinatorics, knowing the story that a formula came from can give a big hint to what proof methods will work.

Answer (score 2):

We seek to show that

$$\sum_{q=0}^K (-1)^q {2n+1-q\choose q}
{2n-2q\choose K-q} = \frac{1}{2} (1+(-1)^K).$$

The LHS is

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|w|=\gamma}
\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|z|=\varepsilon}
\sum_{q=0}^K
(-1)^q \frac{1}{z^{q+1}} (1+z)^{2n+1-q}
\frac{1}{w^{K-q+1}} (1+w)^{2n-2q}
\; dz \; dw
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|w|=\gamma}
\frac{1}{w^{K+1}} (1+w)^{2n}
\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|z|=\varepsilon}
\frac{1}{z} (1+z)^{2n+1}
\\ \times
\sum_{q=0}^K
(-1)^q \frac{1}{z^q} (1+z)^{-q}
w^q (1+w)^{-2q}
\; dz \; dw.$$

Here we may extend $q$ beyond $K$ to infinity because the pole at zero
in $w$ is canceled for the extra values. We obtain

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|w|=\gamma}
\frac{1}{w^{K+1}} (1+w)^{2n}
\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|z|=\varepsilon}
\frac{1}{z} (1+z)^{2n+1}
\\ \times
\frac{1}{1+w/(1+w)^2/z/(1+z)}
\; dz \; dw
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|w|=\gamma}
\frac{1}{w^{K+1}} (1+w)^{2n+2}
\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|z|=\varepsilon}
(1+z)^{2n+2}
\\ \times
\frac{1}{(1+z(1+w))(w+z(1+w))}
\; dz \; dw.$$

The pole at zero in $z$ is gone but a new pole has appeared inside the
contour. Note that when we summed the geometric series we required
$|w/(1+w)^2| \lt |z(1+z)|.$ We have with $\gamma\ll 1$ and
$\varepsilon\ll 1$ that $|w/(1+w)^2| \le  \gamma/(1-\gamma)^2 \lt
2\gamma$ and $|z(1+z)| \ge \varepsilon (1-\varepsilon) \gt
\frac{1}{2}\varepsilon.$ Therefore  taking $\varepsilon = 4\gamma$ will
work e.g. $\gamma=1/11$ and  $\varepsilon = 4/11.$

We have for the first simple pole at  $z_0=-1/(1+w)$ that $|-1/(1+w)| \gt
1/(1+\gamma) \gt 4\gamma =  \varepsilon.$ This pole is not inside the
contour. The second pole is  at $z_1=-w/(1+w)$ and we have $|-w/(1+w)|
\lt \gamma/(1-\gamma) \lt  4\gamma = \varepsilon.$ This pole is inside
the contour. We thus write

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|w|=\gamma}
\frac{1}{w^{K+1}} (1+w)^{2n+1}
\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|z|=\varepsilon}
(1+z)^{2n+2}
\\ \times
\frac{1}{(1+z(1+w))(w/(1+w)+z)}
\; dz \; dw.$$

Evaluating the residue from the simple pole at $z_1$ we find

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|w|=\gamma}
\frac{1}{w^{K+1}} (1+w)^{2n+1}
(1-w/(1+w))^{2n+2} \frac{1}{1-(1+w)w/(1+w)} \; dw
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|w|=\gamma}
\frac{1}{w^{K+1}} \frac{1}{1-w^2} \; dw.$$

This is

$$[w^K] \frac{1}{1-w^2} = \frac{1}{2}(1+(-1)^K)$$

as claimed.

#### Alternate evaluation

Returning to the start we seek

$$\sum_{q=0}^K (-1)^q {2n+1-q\choose q}
{2n-2q\choose K-q} = \frac{1}{2} (1+(-1)^K).$$

With

$${2n-2q\choose K-q} = {2n-2q\choose 2n-K-q} =
\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|w|=\gamma}
\frac{1}{w^{K-q+1}} \frac{1}{(1-w)^{2n-K-q+1}} \; dw$$

the LHS becomes

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|w|=\gamma}
\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|z|=\varepsilon}
\sum_{q=0}^K
(-1)^q \frac{1}{z^{q+1}} (1+z)^{2n+1-q}
\frac{1}{w^{K-q+1}} \frac{1}{(1-w)^{2n-K-q+1}}
\; dz \; dw.$$

Here we may extend the sum to infinity due to the pole at $w=0$
vanishing when $q\gt K.$ This yields

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|w|=\gamma}
\frac{1}{w^{K+1}} \frac{1}{(1-w)^{2n-K+1}}
\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|z|=\varepsilon}
\frac{1}{z} (1+z)^{2n+1}
\\ \times \sum_{q\ge 0}
(-1)^q \frac{1}{z^q} (1+z)^{-q}
w^q (1-w)^{q}
\; dz \; dw
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|w|=\gamma}
\frac{1}{w^{K+1}} \frac{1}{(1-w)^{2n-K+1}}
\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|z|=\varepsilon}
\frac{1}{z} (1+z)^{2n+1}
\\ \times \frac{1}{1+w(1-w)/z/(1+z)}
\; dz \; dw
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|w|=\gamma}
\frac{1}{w^{K+1}} \frac{1}{(1-w)^{2n-K+1}}
\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|z|=\varepsilon}
(1+z)^{2n+2}
\\ \times \frac{1}{z(1+z)+w(1-w)}
\; dz \; dw
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|w|=\gamma}
\frac{1}{w^{K+1}} \frac{1}{(1-w)^{2n-K+1}}
\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|z|=\varepsilon}
(1+z)^{2n+2}
\\ \times \frac{1}{(z+w)(z-(w-1))}
\; dz \; dw.$$

Once more the pole at $z=0$ is gone but a new one has appeared (two of
them, in fact). To see  this note that in the summation of the infinite
series we require for  convergence that $|w(1-w)| \lt |z(1+z)|.$ We have
for $\varepsilon \ll 1$ and $\gamma \ll 1$ that $|z(1+z)|\ge \varepsilon
(1-\varepsilon) \ge \frac{1}{2} \varepsilon$ and $|w(1-w)| \le \gamma
(1+\gamma) \le \frac{3}{2}\gamma.$ Hence $3\gamma \lt \varepsilon$
will work e.g.  take $\gamma = \varepsilon/4$ as in $\gamma = 1/16$ and
$\varepsilon =  1/4.$ In particular $|w|\lt |z|$ so the pole at $z_0=-w$
is inside the  contour. On the other hand the closest that the pole at
$z_1=w-1$ which  is on a circle at $z=-1$, rotating with radius $\gamma$,
gets to the  origin is $1-\gamma =  1 - \varepsilon/4 \gt \varepsilon$ as
long as $\varepsilon \lt 4/5$, so  this is definitely not inside the
contour. Hence the contribution from $z_0 = -w$ is the only one and it
yields

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|w|=\gamma}
\frac{1}{w^{K+1}} \frac{1}{(1-w)^{2n-K+1}}
(1-w)^{2n+2} \frac{1}{1-2w} \; dw
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|w|=\gamma}
\frac{1}{w^{K+1}}
(1-w)^{K+1} \frac{1}{1-2w} \; dw
\\ = \sum_{q=0}^K {K+1\choose q} (-1)^q 2^{K-q}
= - (-1)^{K+1} \frac{1}{2}
+ \frac{1}{2} \sum_{q=0}^{K+1} {K+1\choose q} (-1)^q 2^{K+1-q}
\\ = - (-1)^{K+1} \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} 1^{K+1}
= \frac{1}{2} (1 + (-1)^K).$$

We once more have the claim.

Comment: What a great answer! :-) (+1)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a starter. We transform the sum and separate one part which can be simplified. We start with the left hand side of OPs identity and obtain
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=0}^K&(-1)^i\binom{2n+1-i}{i}\binom{2n-2i}{K-i}\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^K(-1)^i\frac{(2n+1-i)!}{i!(2n+1-2i)!}\,\frac{(2n-2i)!}{(K-i)!(2n-K-i)!}\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^K(-1)^i\binom{K}{i}\binom{2n-i}{K}\frac{2n+1-i}{2n+1-2i}\tag{1}\\
\end{align*}

> With (1) we can reformulate OPs claim for $0\leq K\leq 2n$ as
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{i=0}^K(-1)^i\binom{K}{i}\binom{2n-i}{K}\frac{2n+1-i}{2n+1-2i}=\frac{1}{2}\left(1+(-1)^K\right)}\tag{2}
> \end{align*}

We can write the left-hand side of (2) as
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=0}^K(-1)^i\binom{K}{i}\binom{2n-i}{K}\left(1+\frac{i}{2n+1-2i}\right)\tag{3}
\end{align*}
In the following we use the *coefficient of* operator $[z^n]$ to denote the coefficient of $z^n$ of a series. This way we can write for instance
\begin{align*}
[z^p](1+z)^q=\binom{q}{p}\tag{4}
\end{align*}

> We obtain from (3)
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{i=0}^K}&\color{blue}{(-1)^i\binom{K}{i}\binom{2n-i}{K}}\\
> &=\sum_{i=0}^K(-1)^i\binom{K}{k}\binom{2n-i}{2n-i-K}\tag{5.1}\\
> &=\sum_{i=0}^K(-1)^i\binom{K}{i}[z^{2n-i-K}](1+z)^{2n-i}\tag{5.2}\\
> &=[z^{2n-K}](1+z)^{2n}\sum_{i=0}^K\binom{K}{i}\left(-\frac{z}{1+z}\right)^i\tag{5.3}\\
> &=[z^{2n-k}](1+z)^{2n}\left(1-\frac{z}{1+z}\right)^K\tag{5.4}\\
> &=[z^{2n-k}](1+z)^{2n-K}\\
> &=\binom{2n-K}{2n-K}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=1}\tag{5.5}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (5.1) we use $\binom{p}{q}=\binom{p}{p-q}$.
- In (5.2) we use (3).
- In (5.3) we use $[z^{p-q}]A(z)=[z^p]z^qA(z)$.
- In (5.4) we apply the binomial theorem and do some simplifications in the following steps.

> We also obtain from (3)
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{i=1}^K}&\color{blue}{(-1)^i\binom{K}{i}\binom{2n-i}{K}\frac{i}{2n+1-2i}}\\
> &=K\sum_{i=1}^K(-1)^i\binom{K-1}{i-1}\binom{2n-i}{K}\frac{1}{2n+1-2i}\tag{6.1}\\
> &=K\sum_{i=0}^{K-1}(-1)^{i+1}\binom{K-1}{i}\binom{2n-i-1}{K}\frac{1}{2n-1-2i}\tag{6.2}\\
> &=K\sum_{i=0}^{K-1}(-1)^{i+1}\binom{K-1}{i}\binom{2n-i-1}{2n-i-1-K}\frac{1}{2n-1-2i}\tag{6.3}\\
> &\color{blue}{=(-1)^KK\sum_{i=0}^{K-1}\binom{K-1}{i}\binom{-K-1}{2n-i-1-K}\frac{1}{2n-1-2i}}\tag{6.4}\\
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (6.1) we use $\binom{p}{q}=\frac{p}{q}\binom{p-1}{q-1}$.
- In (6.2) we shift the index to start with $i=0$.
- In (6.3) we use $\binom{p}{q}=\binom{p}{p-q}$.
- In (6.4) we use $\binom{-p}{q}=\binom{p+q-1}{q}(-1)^q$.

> We finally derive from (3), (5.5) and (6.4) the following claim
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{K\sum_{i=0}^{K-1}\binom{K-1}{i}\binom{-K-1}{2n-i-1-K}\frac{1}{2n-1-2i}=\frac{1}{2}\left(1-(-1)^K\right)}
> \end{align*}
> which could alternatively be used to prove OPs claim.