# Regarding Egorychev integrals for binomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, complex-analysis, reference-request, binomial-coefficients, book-recommendation

I've been searching for references that deals with the Egorychev methods and particularly with the integral representations for binomial coefficients.

$$\binom{n}{k}=\frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_{|z|<\infty}\frac{(1+z)^n}{z^{k+1}}dz$$
and
$$\binom{n}{k}=\frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_{|z|<1}\frac{dz}{(1-z)^{k+1}z^{n-k+1}}$$
My doubt here is, when to use each one? I've seen problems here on MSE where both are used but couldn't figure out when to choose over another.
Also I managed to get (?) a sketch of a proof but i would like to see this in the depth it deserves, and there's where I haven't had luck finding references. I am aware of
[Marko Riedel](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/44883/marko-riedel) pdf about the Egorychev method and the Egorychev book itself. But there's no more besides these? And why isn't this more popular and used? I don't remember seeing these results in complex analysis books (not that I can remember at least).

Anyway, thanks in advance if anyone can answer the question about when to use each case and/or conditions to consider to choose.

Answer (score 8):

*Ordering of machinery*

This is, as the reader may have noticed, a profound question. The
introduction by Markus Scheuer is  very good work.  Here are some
comments  that  may  help  to  continue  exploring.   First,  the
Egorychev method has  three stages, Egorychev I,  which is formal
power series, Egorychev II, which is Egorychev's residue calculus
as presented in  the book, and Egorychev  III, complex variables,
also as in the book. These  are ordered by subset inclusion.  The
reader should  **try them  in turn**.   So use  complex variables
only when necessary (last).   This classification originates with
Hosam Mahmoud and is presented in  a recent paper, to be found at
the                      following                      [Springer
link](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s44007-023-00065-y).
At  this  time  my  compilation is  in  chronological  order  and
presents Egorychev III before Egorychev I and II.

*Types of binomial coefficients*

What integrals and  contours to use depends on  the **behavior of
the binomial coefficient that is  desired**. For example with the
first one

$${a\choose b} = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_{|z|=\rho}
\frac{(1+z)^a}{z^{b+1}} \; dz.$$

we can actually  get two types of binomial  coefficients. We have
with $0\lt\rho\lt  1$ that we obtain  a zero value when  $b\lt 0$
because the pole  at zero has disappeared. But now  when $a\lt 0$
and $a\gt b$  a new pole appears at $z=-1.$  Therefore when $1\lt
\rho \lt \infty$ we get the value

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_{|z|=\rho} 
\frac{1}{(1+z)^{-a}} z^{-b-1} \; dz
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_{|z|=\rho} 
\frac{1}{(1+z)^{-a}}
\sum_{q=0}^{-b-1} {-b-1\choose q} (1+z)^q (-1)^{-b-1-q} \; dz
\\ = {-b-1\choose -a-1} (-1)^{a-b}
= {-b-1 \choose a-b} (-1)^{a-b} = {a\choose a-b}.$$

This is the  definition that Maple uses,  giving e.g. ${-6\choose
-8} =  21.$ With $a\ge b$  the falling factorial applies,  as in,
$a^{\underline{a-b}}/(a-b)!$. Nonetheless it  must be pointed out
that there  are combinatorial  problems where  the first  type is
wanted.  Egorychev lists four integrals on page 26 of the book to
evaluate a single binomial coefficient in a certain sum, choosing
the one that features the first type.

*Example of two types of integrals*

There    is   a    post    of   mine    at    this   [MSE    link
4597569](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4597569/) where
we  can  compare the  two  integrals  and  their effects  on  the
computation. This appears to be a problem that requires Egorychev
III  and  cannot  be  done  with Egorychev  I  and  II.  The  two
computations  are  very  similar  where  effort  and  inputs  are
concerned  and  we would  not  necessarily  prefer one  over  the
other. It would  seem there is no alternative to  doing both once
sums  of  a  certain  complexity  enter  into  the  game.  As  an
additional  observation, should  an infinite  series appear  that
corresponds to an expansion about infinity the pole at the origin
could  vanish. In  that case,  choose a  different representation
that yields an expansion about zero. We do this all the time with
Egorychev  I,  because formal  power  series  have no  notion  of
converging  in  a  certain   contour.  Sometimes  we  choose  the
representation that  makes the rule  $[z^{n-k}] f(z) =  [z^n] z^k
f(z)$ go  through because  it means we  may move  the coefficient
extractor outside of the sum.

Comment: Many thanks for providing this instructive answer - and many thanks for publishing the paper together with Hosam Mahmoud which presents a wealth of structured ideas to successfully master even challenging binomial identities. (+1)

Comment: Thank you very much Marko for your answer, and for the papers as well :D. At first when I stumbled upon solving those sums applying complex contour integration I though it was an absolute overkill, but once I understood where it all was going I realized how amazing it was. And as always, the rabbit hole is always much deeper as one can expect.

Answer (score 7):

Keywords to look for applications of this kind are *[residue calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem#Calculation_of_Residues)* and *[Cauchy integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula)*
in books of combinatorics.

OPs examples taken from Marko Riedels *[paper](https://pnp.mathematik.uni-stuttgart.de/iadm/Riedel/papers/egorychev.pdf)* are two useful representations of the binomial coefficient $\binom{n}{k}$ using the residue calculus, which is used here as technique to extract a coefficient of a series expansion.

- In the first case we select the coefficient of $z^k$ from the polynomial $(1+z)^n$. We obtain
  \begin{align*}
  \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_{|z|<\infty}\frac{(1+z)^n}{z^{k+1}}dz
  &=[z^k](1+z)^n\color{blue}{=\binom{n}{k}}\tag{1}
  \end{align*}
- In the second case we select the coefficient of $z^{n-k}$ from the binomial series expansion $(1-z)^{-k-1}$ at $z=0$. We obtain
  \begin{align*}
  \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_{|z|<1}\frac{dz}{(1-z)^{k+1}z^{n-k+1}}\
  &=[z^{n-k}](1-z)^{-k-1}\\
  &=[z^{n-k}]\sum_{q=0}^{\infty}\binom{-k-1}{q}(-z)^q\\
  &=\binom{-k-1}{n-k}(-1)^{n-k}\\
  &\,\,\color{blue}{=\binom{n}{k}}\tag{2}
  \end{align*}

Here we also use the *coefficient of* operator $[z^k]$ to denote the coefficient of $z^k$ of a series. On the other hand, whenever we see this operator $[z^k]$ in use we can interpret it as application of the residue calculus in disguise.

*Note:* It is usually a matter of experience which of the representations $(1+z)^n$ in (1) or $(1-z)^{-k-1}$ in (2) is the right choice for an appropriate simplification of the expression under consideration.

**Some references:**

- *[Mathematics for the Analysis of Algorithms](https://maa.org/press/maa-reviews/mathematics-for-the-analysis-of-algorithms)* by D. H. Greene and D. E. Knuth. In section 4.3.2 *Residue Calculus* there are examples for the Hadamard product and the diagonalisation of series. Given
  \begin{align*}
   F(w,z)=\sum_{m,n\geq 0}\binom{m+n}{n}w^mz^n=\frac{1}{1-w-z}
   \end{align*}
  we have the diagonalisation of $F(w,z)$:
  \begin{align*}
  G(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{C}\frac{dt}{(1-t-z/t)t}=\sum_{n}{\binom{2n}{n}}z^n
  \end{align*}
- *[Combinatorial Enumeration](https://arxiv.org/abs/2209.10075v1)* by I. P. Goulden and D. M. Jackson. In section I.2.3 *An Identity (by Residue Composition)* the residue calculus is used to show the identity
  \begin{align*}
  \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{2n+1}{2k+1}\binom{j+k}{2n}=\binom{2j}{2n}
  \end{align*}
- *[Advanced Combinatorics](https://archive.org/details/Comtet_Louis_-_Advanced_Coatorics)* by L. Comtet. We find already in Section I.12: *Formal Series* the diagonalisation example, but here in the context of formal power series.
- *[Enumerative Combinatorics, Vol. II](https://maa.org/press/maa-reviews/enumerative-combinatorics-vol-ii)* by R. P. Stanley
  This classic presents besides many other examples of the residue calculus also the diagonalisation example in section 6.3 *Diagonals* which contains a thorough treatment of this theme.
- *[Generating Functionology](https://maa.org/press/maa-reviews/generatingfunctionology)* by H. S. Wilf. See for instance *Cauchy's formula* which is formula (2.25) in section 2.4 *Power Series, Analytic Theory*.
- *[Analytic Combinatorics](https://maa.org/press/maa-reviews/analytic-combinatorics)* by P. Flajolet and R. Sedgewick. Here I finally like to cite Theorem IV.4 from section IV.2 *Analytic and meromorphic functions*:

  - **Theorem IV.4 (Cauchy's Coefficient Formula)**. Let $f(z)$ be analytic in a region $\Omega$ containing $0$ and let $\lambda$ be a simple loop around $0$ in $\Omega$ that is positively oriented. Then, the coefficient $[z^n]f(z)$ admits the integral representation
    \begin{align*}
    \color{blue}{f_n\equiv [z^n]f(z)=\frac{1}{2i \pi}\int_{\lambda}f(z)\frac{dz}{z^{n+1}}}.
    \end{align*}

Comment: thank you so much Markus!

Comment: @ppmbb: You're welcome. :-)